# Adding database to my fragment but nothing shows up

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-fragments

I'm working on a simple Notepad app. I added a database to my fragment, but when I run the app it does not show up.

Here is my fragment code. Everything seems to work fine but nothing appears on the app. I called the database in `onActivityCreated`.

```
public class TomorrowFragment extends Fragment   {
  NDb myNDb;
public TomorrowFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tomorrow, container, false);
}
/**
 * how i called my DataBase
 */
@Override
public void onActivityCreated( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    myNDb = new NDb(getActivity());

   }
}
```

Here is the database code:

```
public NDb(Context context) {
    super(context, dbname, null, 1);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("create table mynotes"
            + "(_id integer primary key, name text,remark text,dates     text)");
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)      

   {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + mynotes);
    onCreate(db);
}

public Cursor fetchAll() {

    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(mynotes, new String[] { "_id", "name",
            "dates", "remark" }, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }

    return mCursor;
}

public boolean insertNotes(String name, String dates, String remark) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("dates", dates);
    contentValues.put("remark", remark);
    db.insert(mynotes, null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public Cursor getData(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor z = db.rawQuery("select * from " + mynotes + " where _id=" + id
            + "", null);
    return z;
}

public int numberOfRows() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, mynotes);
    return numRows;
}

public boolean updateNotes(Integer id, String name, String dates,
                           String remark) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);
    contentValues.put("dates", dates);
    contentValues.put("remark", remark);
    db.update(mynotes, contentValues, "_id = ? ",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
    return true;
}

public Integer deleteNotes(Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(mynotes, "_id = ? ",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}
public ArrayList getAll() {
    ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + mynotes, null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    while (res.isAfterLast() == false) {
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(remark)));
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(dates)));
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(name)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
}
```

Here is the logcat output:
[image]

Comment: You are instantiating your database but not doing anything with it. You need to query the data and then add code to display the data on whatever views you want in a layout.  I suggest doing some basic Android development tutorials before delving into a larger piece of code without understanding the fundamentals. Specifically, database and Android layout tutorials will help you in this case.